# Getting an runtime exception using addTarget:Action:forControlEvents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I am trying to use *addTarget:Action:forControlEvents* but I am receiving a runtime exception for an unrecognized selector.

This is being called from a *UIView* subclass in *initWithFrame*. 
Below is my code:

```
myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[myButton addTarget:self action:&selector(displayList:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

My method:

```
-(void)displayList:(id)sender
```

When I click on the button it receive the following message:

`-[MyClass displayList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[MyClass displayList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.`

*MyClass* is a custom control that is a *UIView* subclass with a *UIButton* and *UILabel*. This class is going to be placed on a ViewController of another application.

I'm not sure what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

it should read

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

@ instead of &

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:&selector(displayList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The syntax is @selector(displayList:)
Also, there is a change your button may not fire the event. Try creating it this way:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; //this will return an autoreleased UIButton object, be careful.
button.frame = CGRectMake(...);
...
```

Comment: Could it be a visiblity problem? If displayList is in the custom control class and that class is being used in another application, would it find the displayList method?

Comment: The displayList method must be implemented in the custom UIView class you have, if you have added self as target.

Comment: It is in the same UIView class.

Comment: If the UIView class is used in another application, it should still be able to get to the displayList method, correct?

Comment: This exception is being thrown by the application that is using this class.